# WebStorm - move cursor up/down with several lines

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In WebStorm (or generally in any JetBrains editor) when you click <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow cursor moves with one line up or down.

Can I create a shortcut to move the cursor with multiple lines up or down?

For example: when we click <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> cursor comes up/down with three lines.

Comment: Record a macro where you move up/down desired number of lines .. and then just assign shortcut to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can record a macro (`Edit | Macros`) where you move caret up or down desired number of lines
2. Assign any desired shortcut at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap | Macros`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html